# Prove that a random variable with a random index is a random variable (assuming the sample path continuous) (probably related to stopping time)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

This problem comes from *A Probability Path*, 3.4.20.

Suppose $\left\{X_{t}, t \geq 0\right\}$ is a continuous time stochastic process on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P)$ whose paths are continuous. We can understand this to mean that for each $t \geq 0, X_{t}: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable and, for each $\omega \in \Omega$, the function $t \mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$ is continuous; that is a member of $C[0, \infty)$. Let $\tau: \Omega \mapsto[0, \infty)$ be a random variable and define the process stopped at $\tau$ as the function $X_{\tau}: \Omega \mapsto[0, \infty)$ defined by
$$
X_{\tau}(\omega):=X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega), \quad \omega \in \Omega
$$
Prove $X_{\tau}$ is a random variable.

(It seems that the proof of this problem doesn't need the direct use of filtration, since it comes so early in the book:)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Measurabilty of $\tau$ implies that the map $\omega \to (\omega,\tau(\omega))$ is measuarble. The map $(w,t)\to X_t(\omega)$ is measurable by continuity of paths.  If you compose these two maps you get $\omega \to X_{\tau(\omega)} (\omega)$.

[Let $X_n(t,\omega))=X_{[2^{n}t]/2^{n}}(\omega)$. By continuity of paths $X_n(t,\omega)) \to X(t,\omega)$ for each $\omega$ and $t$. It is easy to show that $(w,t)\to X_n(t,\omega)$  is measurable using the fact that $X_{[2^{n}t]/2^{n}}$ is a random variable. Hence, $(w,t)\to X_t(\omega)$ is measurable. (Notation: $X(t,\omega) \equiv X_t(\omega)$].

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a bit confused about proving the measurability of $(\omega,t)\to X_t(\omega)$ by using the continuity of paths.

Comment: @W672 I have added some steps.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I got another problem. When we are discussing the measurability of $X_n(\omega, t)$, we still have to prove that it is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, not only with respect to $\mathcal{B}$. And I think it is not that direct from the fact that $X_t$ is a random variable for every $t$.

Comment: $X_n(t,\omega)=\sum_i X_{(i-1)2^{-n}} (\omega) I_{(i-1)/2^{n} \leq t <i/2^{n}}$. Product of a measurable function of $\omega$ and  a measurable function of $t$ is jointly measurable and sums of measurable functions are measurable.

Comment: Got it, thank you!